# Day-Caring a Pokémon will have same effect as leveling it up by battling?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

I am playing the 3rd generation Pokémon games now. I completed Sapphire and want to go to the Battle Tower with a level 50 Pokémon and I've found quite a lot of Rare Candies by using the Zigzagoon Strategy.

These are my concerns:

1. If I used Rare Candies on one Pokémon to increase its level, it would **technically** not get EVs, right? Or is it just a myth? It would be weaker than a Pokémon who has leveled up to the same level by battling? Is that right?
2. If I give my Pokémon to the day-care couple, will the increase in level also increase my EVs or it will have the same effect as Rare Candies (assuming this myth is true)?

Comment: This is easily answered by a Google search

Comment: EVs from battling are determined by the species of Pokémon you defeat. Where could they be coming from for the other methods? What could determine which ones you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to earn EVs in generation 3 games is through battling or medicines such as Iron and Zinc.